# how to call functions on server side in node.js

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to know how to call server functions in node.js aside from using socket.io(sockets).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean from the browser? There are many ways, such as using ajax, since  you don't want to use web  sockets. There are also ways to share server modules with the client, using libraries like [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) or [express-expose](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-expose).

Comment: calling server functions from the client. though i think epress-expose is an answer to my problem thanks by the way.